# Is there a way of accessing the "Comments" associated with an EKEvent?

Tags: ios, ekevent

If I create a EKEventViewController and pass it an event for which I am not the organizer, I see an "Add Comments" button at the bottom.

Is there any way to read from or write to this programmatically? I can't see anything in the EK docs.

cheers

Phil

Comment: Well, I am sorry to put this comment in an answer, but I read the FAQ and couldn't find the little comments box anywhere on my screen. I just want to ask Phil if he ever figured out how to access "comments" programmatically? I would like to do same. Laura

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for the notes property an an EKCalendarItem, which EKEvent is a subclass of.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/EventKit/Reference/EKCalendarItemClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010882

Comment: Nope. Notes are stored on the calendar event (server-side). Comments are (I believe) just stored on the device. Either way, the notes property is not the same as the comments i.e. if you add comments to an event it does not show up in the notes property.